# convert list conatining strings to dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list that has strings in it, in the form of key:value pairs, something like this

```
d = ['"id.resp_h": [loopback, unicast, multicast, interface_local_multicast, link_local_unicast, link_local_multicast, unspecified]',
 '"id.orig_h": {{ sensor_subnets }}']
```

and I need to convert it into a dictionary. I've tried many solutions like using `json.loads()` or `ast.literal_eval()` but none work.

Any suggestions??

Thanks:)

Comment: The example you attached is not a valid python list. Could you show us your code so we can try to help you?

Comment: @hhimko it is a valid list (note single quotees which makes it a list of strings).  However, the list of strings don't appear to be serialized from a valid data structure.

Comment: Is `{{sensor_subnets}}` a valid form of the python syntax?

Comment: @DarrylG what about the variable names inside the strings such as `loopback` or `sensor_subnets`?  These names are not wrapped in quotes, so they are definitely not strings. Should they be linked to existing variables or converted to actual strings?

Comment: @hhimko as mentioned the list is valid (i.e. try print(d)).  However, it doesn't seem to be convertible because of things such as `{{ sensor_subnets }}`.  The tokens such as loopback, unicast, multicast we could take as strings i.e. 'loopback', 'unicast', etc.  But, `{{ 'sensor_subnets' }}`  would be a set of sets, which is invalid since sets are not hashable.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `{{sensor_subnets}}` is not a valid syntax, and it'll throw the exception `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`.
Another problem is that the values in the list are not string, and they're interpreted as variables.

if you convert the values in the list to strings, and also change `{{sensor_subnets}}` to  `{"sensor_subnets"}`, you can use the [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

appropriate `d` should be like this:

```
d = ['"id.resp_h": ["loopback", "unicast", "multicast", "interface_local_multicast", "link_local_unicast", "link_local_multicast", "unspecified"]', '"id.orig_h": {"sensor_subnets"}']
```

```
import ast
out_dict = {}
for key_val in d:
   new_dict = ast.literal_eval("{"+key_val+"}")
   out_dict.update(new_dict)
print(out_dict)
```

output:

```
{'id.resp_h': ['loopback', 'unicast', 'multicast', 'interface_local_multicast', 'link_local_unicast', 'link_local_multicast', 'unspecified'], 'id.orig_h': {'sensor_subnets'}}
```